# javascript input field for web address and submit button to open that web address

Tags: javascript, input, hyperlink, field

I have an input field for web address and once I put in the web address, example "yahoo.com", I'd like the button to open that address in new tab or window.

```html
<input type="text" width="30%" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="hlight2" value="Submit"  onClick="javascript: window.open();" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)
You should be using an anchor tag instead of a button anyway

Comment: thank you, but @mplungjan answered my question ... i will check this out also though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
document.getElementById("hlight2").addEventListener("click",function() {
  const loc = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (loc) window.open(loc,"_blank");
})
```

Better (pressing enter also pops the window)

```js
document.getElementById("urlForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const loc = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (loc) window.open(loc, "_blank");
})
```

```html
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="text" width="30%" id="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: oh hey thanks, but no server side, all local personal webpage i'm trying to create. i get "file:///home/chronos/u-xxxxxx/MyFiles/Downloads/www.yahoo.com" ... is there a way to open the link --> https://www.yahoo.com ?

Comment: You need to add https://

Comment: super. thank you!  i modified and added  "https://" -->  window.open("https://"+loc, "_blank");